# Flutter download file from iOS device

Tags: flutter

Flutter, for android, I can access app folder from android studio's Device File Explorer.

How can I access app folder for iOS device. I need to check downloaded file from iOS device to check file is corrupted or not. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you installed the app already or is it just the IPA file downloaded on the phone?

Comment: Yes, app is already installed. I found the answer. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Xcode, go to Window > Devices and Simulators

2.In the Devices tab, select your application, then click on the Gear icon, then click Download Container...

3.Choose the location you want to save the file, then click on Save.

Go to Finder and find the .xcappdata file you just downloaded, then right-click and select Show Package Contents

4. The contents folder will open. Your .sql file is in AppData > Documents > Your_DB_Here